# Is it possible to make a new string in a foreach loop?

Tags: c#

```
int x = 0;
string1 = "Hi,Bye";
string[] string2 = string1.Split(",");

foreach (string item in string2)
{
   string x = item;
   x++;
}
```

Now is there any way to actually accomplish making a new string with a "preset" name with the string? Hopefully I was clear enough for you to understand what I want to do, but it's kind of hard to explain this.

Comment: What's your desired output?

Comment: I am afraid it is not clear at all. The example will also not compile as you have two declaration for a variable `x`. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: My desired output? I would love for it to separate `"Hi"` and `"Bye"`, and to put the into a new string all while my program is running.

Comment: Guys I think he/she is trying to change the foreach `item` - by way of the x reference to it. Thats where the problem is.

Comment: What do you intend to achieve with the string x that you've defined? What "preset" value will you add? And as Oded said, it won't compile in any case.

Comment: You want two new strings "Hi" and "Bye"?

Comment: `put the into a new string`? Each one into the **same** string? You already have them as two _separate_ strings in the `string2` array. Not sure what you are trying to do here.

Comment: @Oded That's the whole point. Lets say once string2 splits string1 into "Hi" and "Bye" I want them to put into two different strings. For "Hi" the string name would be "0", and since x now equals 1 the string name that contains "Bye" would be "1". I know this really hard to understand, but hopefully that helped clear things up a little more.

Comment: You can't create variables with names that are generated in runtime.

Comment: That's the array - it already collects all the strings in an indexable structure. You can't create dynamic variable names - pretty much in any language.

Comment: @JeremyThompson Exactly what I'm trying to get at! And for an example of the string that I want to split: "test1,test2/test3,test4" the first time I'm splitting the string from the "/" then I want it to put into a new string. From there I want to split it even further from the "," but first I have to put "test1,test2" and "test3,test4" into two new strings.

Comment: @Oded Oh alright. Thanks again! This pretty much cleared things up for me. I wish I could be more clear.

Answer (score 2):

Dont increment the `int` variable x.

Iterating over a foreach loop, the `item` in the `string2` array will jump to the next value in the array.

```
string1 = "Hi,Bye";
string[] string2 = string1.Split(",");

foreach (string item in string2)
{
   Console.Write(item);
}
```

If you were you using a for loop then the code would look like this (and this may have cause confusion):

```
string[] string2 = string1.Split(",");

for(int x = 0; x < string2.Length; x++)
{
   Console.Write(string2[x]);
}
```

**Edit:**

example of the string that I want to split: "test1,test2/test3,test4" the first time I'm splitting the string from the "/" then I want it to put into a new string. From there I want to split it even further from the "," but first I have to put "test1,test2" and "test3,test4" into two new strings

```
string s =  "test1,test2/test3,test4";
string[] arr = s.Split('/');
string stringTestOneAndTwo = arr[0];
string stringTestThreeAndFour = arr[1];
string[] subArr1 = arr[0].Split(',');
string[] subArr2 = arr[1].Split(',');
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't exactly understand your question. But did you try to use `List<>`?

```
string s = "test1,test2/test3,test4";
string[] subStrings1 = s.Split('/');
List<string[]> subStrings2 = new List<string[]>();
foreach (string item in subStrings1)
{
    string[] tempArray = item.Split(',');
    subStrings2.Add(tempArray);
}
```